# sharing data to other apps not working in higher version

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my app, I am sharing my videos to another app, it works fine on older version devices but not working in higher versions more than 5.0 (marshmallow). I am doing this in a fragment.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("video/*");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(currentFile));
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share to"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: The app was just crashing in higher version operating mobiles

Comment: Open your logcat and search for `fatal` errors. And post it.

Comment: I'll post (please wait) , thanks for the suggestion

Comment: How is this question related to `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ShareCompat.IntentBuilder:

```
Intent shareIntent =   ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(YourActivity.this)
                                                    .setChooserTitle("Share to")
                                                    .setType("video/*")
                                                    .setStream(Uri.fromFile(currentFile))
                                                    .getIntent();
                            if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                                startActivity(shareIntent);
                            }
```

Refer to this documentation : [ShareCompat.IntentBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the support .

I have solved the issuse using the concept of Sharing files using FileProvider